# How do you sanitize an input in wordpress

Tags: sql, wordpress

i want to know what wordpress build-in function you will use when sanitizing specific input ? for example an sql query, numeric, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look here:

[Using Wordpress, can some one tell me the best way of sanitizing input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127009/using-wordpress-can-some-one-tell-me-the-best-way-of-sanitizing-input)